# Почему std::optional не вызывает Value-initialization хранящегося значения? С++

Tags: c++, инициализация

Есть такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

struct Def {
    int i;
    Def() : i(10) {std::cout << "DEF DEFAULt" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {

    std::optional<Def> opt {};
    std::cout << opt->i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Я использую Value-initialization при объявлении переменной типа `optional`, значит для всех его переменных-членов должна также применяться value-initialization. Это также значит, что должен вызваться конструктор моей структуры и инициализировать i значением 10 и вывести сообщение. Почему этого не происходит? Optional же как-то хранит объект моей структуры, тогда почему для нее не вызывается user-defined конструктор по умолчанию при value-initialization?

Comment: Нет, объект optional изначально ничего не хранит.

Comment: @user7860670 я ниже написал более подробно, что хотел изложить

Comment: optional как раз и может создавать объект вашего класса в рантайме. В нем нет полей с типом "ваш объект". Там есть поле, предоставляющее достаточно места под объект.

Comment: @user7860670 `union` что ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что по умолчанию, оно создается пустым (то есть, объект не создается).

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional

> 1. Constructs an object that **does not contain a value**.

Проверка очень простая

```
std::cout << opt.has_value()  << "\n";
```

А вот то, что удалось обратится к переменной - обычное UB, ничего необычного. int, как и много других примитивных типов очень терпимы к подобному.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*

> The behavior is undefined if *this does not contain a value.

Comment: Вы не поняли меня. Я знаю про принципы работы optional и про UB знаю. Вопрос в том, что optional должен иметь переменную-член, которая была бы объектом моего класса. Он же не может создать у себя переменную в рантайме, верно? Так вот если у нас есть переменная-член, которая хранит мой объект, то почему для этой переменной-члена не вызывается конструктор при Value-initialization

Comment: Это Вы меня неправильно поняли. Если объект создавать, тогда зачем optional? можно и бульку завести. Не все объекты можно просто так взять и создать. `должен иметь переменную-член, которая была бы объектом моего класса` - нет, не должен. Ему никто не мешает просто выделить достаточное кол-во памяти и вызывать in-place конструктор (что он похоже и делает - https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/optional#L220

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, пока сложно разобраться в этой коляске кода, но я постараюсь) Я понимаю что делает optional, но как он может хранить переменную без переменной-члена я пока не понимаю

Comment: он просто хранит массив байт подходящего размера. все. А потом просто делает placement new.